# Getting extra lines along the TextureRegion in AndEngine (Android)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am getting an extra line (i.e. 1 pixel) along with the TextureRegions. Here is my code where I am making textureRegions. I also tried to give a 1 pixel padding between the TextureRegions, but it didn't work. The size of my image is 132x24.

```
    this.txAt_Paddles = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 64,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.txRg_paddle_left = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.txAt_Paddles, this, "paddle_left.png", 0,0);
    this.txRg_paddle_right = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.txAt_Paddles, this, "paddle_right.png", 0,24);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.txAt_Paddles);
```

Can anyone point out the reson why I am getting these lines at different sides of the different TextureRegions. These lines are not on all the sides of the TextureRegions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the workaround [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post25355.html#p25355) to get rid of those funky lines. As far as I can tell, they are just a result of improper padding somewhere. I'm still working to understand *why* the solution works, but it did!

Comment: I tried the code in that post, but still getting the lines, randomly.

Comment: Check out the link again for another technique. Whalabi loaded the entire texture with a transparent png and then loaded everything on top of that. Worked for me too, and I like it better than extending the TextureFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use the AndEngine but normally when this happens to me its because I have set OpenGL to GL_NEAREST which looks takes two pixels either side of the target pixel to approximate the colour. If the same thing is happening to you it may be looking to far to the left/right of your image...

Try making the width/height of your texture smaller (not the actual image size but this size you are telling the AndEngine)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a padding of at least 1.
I heartily suggest that you use the BuildableTextureAtlas.

Here the code

```
 BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas text =  new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
  //note: no warring of positioning
 TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(text, this, "my image");
 [...]
 try 
    {
        text.build(new BlackPawnTextureBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(2));
    } catch (final TextureAtlasSourcePackingException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

 this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mBuildableTexture);
```

Comment: I have tried padding of 1pixel but of no use. The lines are still showing up randomly on sprites.